# How to apply a blending mode effect to a UIImage?

Tags: ios, swift, image, uiimage

I have a UIImage that I would like to apply an Overlay effect to. Ive set the UIImage using an IBOutlet

```
@IBOutlet weak var monsBgIBO: UIImageView!
monsBgIBO.image = UIImage(named: "spinBall")
```

It is in a UIView with a clear background color. This UIView is in front of the apps background image. Ive been reading up on documentation and I can apply an overlay effect using `CGBlendmode`.

However, upon trying to apply the effect I believe I need to convert my `UIImage` to a `CGImage`. I've been struggling to figure out how to do this.

Answer (score -1):

To convert a UIImage to a CGImage, you simply get its `cgImage` [property](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiimage/1624147-cgimage) (assuming it hasn't been created from a `CIImage`).

It's not clear if its applicable in your case, but you might take a look at [UIVisualEffectView](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uivisualeffectview) as well.